# Modal Pop up in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, mobile-application

I want to implement a pop up modal using swift .I have to implement such that I get one more pop up according to the response (Yes/No), tapped by user.How can I implement this ?
Any Help will be really helpful.

Comment: check this library may it help https://github.com/MarioIannotta/MIBlurPopup

Answer (score 4):

UIAlertController is designed for this purpose.

```
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Default AlertController", message: "A standard alert", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
            println("you have pressed the No button");
            //Call another alert here
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
            println("you have pressed Yes button");
            //Call another alert here
        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: I was aware about this alert controller but the scenario is I have to make a custom modal pop up, How can I implement a customized pop up?

Comment: The simple way to do that is, Put UIView with a transparent background. Add one more view on top of it which acts as popup. Now start designing that UIView.

Comment: OK, that seems a better approach .I will surely implement .Thanks :)

Comment: showing and hiding this pop with few animation basics, will meet your requirement. Otherwise, if you are okay with using third party libraries(which is not recommended always) there are many to use.